# Correct NHibernate Mapping For Stored Procedure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, mapping

---

**UPDATE: This is now resolved, see answer below.**

---

I am having a bit of trouble trying to work out the correct way to write an NHibernate Mapping File (.hbm.xml) for a MSSQL Stored Procedure.

The Stored Procedure accepts two parameters and returns a single row result set containing several columns which have integer values.

My mapping file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="TestApp.DataAccess"
                   namespace="TestApp.DataAccess.Models">

  <class name="MonthlyInstructionCount" lazy="true">
    <id name="Id" column="Month">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="Month" />
    <property name="MapRequests" />
    <property name="Instructions" />
    <property name="DrainsLookSee" />
    <property name="DrainsFullCctv" />
    <property name="Soils" />
    <property name="Roots"/>
    <property name="Arb" />

    <loader query-ref="MI_MonthlyInstructionCount"/>
  </class>

  <sql-query name="MI_MonthlyInstructionCount">
    <return class ="MonthlyInstructionCount">
      <return-property name="Month" column="Month" />
      <return-property name="MapRequests" column="MapRequests" />
      <return-property name="Instructions" column="Instructions" />
      <return-property name="DrainsLookSee" column="DrainsLookSee" />
      <return-property name="DrainsFullCctv" column="DrainsFullCctv" />
      <return-property name="Soils" column="Soils" />
      <return-property name="Roots" column="Roots" />
      <return-property name="Arb" column="Arb" />
    </return>
    exec dbo.MI_MonthlyInstructionCount :StartDate :NumberOfMonths
  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have also tried the following, as suggested by someone on a forum for a similar problem another person was having relating to Stored Procedures...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="TestApp.DataAccess"
                   namespace="TestApp.DataAccess.Models">

  <sql-query name="MI_MonthlyInstructionCount">
    <return class ="MonthlyInstructionCount" />
    exec dbo.MI_MonthlyInstructionCount :StartDate :NumberOfMonths
  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Neither of which seem to work... I just get the following error:

> The type initializer for
>   'TestApp.DataAccess.Sql.NHibernateHelper'
>   threw an exception.
>
> {"Errors in named queries:
>   {MI_MonthlyInstructionCount}"}

I can't see it being the Stored Procedure (though the error would suggest it is...) as it seems to run successfully in MSSQL Server Manager.

Any help is much appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: Is there a reason that MonthlyInstructionCount needs to be a mapped class? It isn't clear from your example, but I would think that this would be a DTO and is probably better handled using projection..

Comment: Ultimately I need to display a table of "Instruction Counts" over a 6 month period. We have already written a DataTable-like component that can display lists of objects, so we would like to use that to display this information. Our DataTable component needs a data source in the form of IEnumerable<T>. Hence the reason for needing a mapped class. We need to be able to pass it a IEnumerable<MonthlyInstructionCount> as its data source. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RESOLVED:** I have now resolved this issue. First of all there was the issue of the ID property being set to "name=Id" instead of "name=Month". Secondly, I had to wrap the exec command in a CDATA and also put a comma seperator between the parameters. The full working mapping file is below for future reference to anyone experiencing a similar problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="TestApp.DataAccess"
                   namespace="TestApp.DataAccess.Models">

  <class name="MonthlyInstructionCount" lazy="true">
    <id name="Month">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="MapRequests" />
    <property name="Instructions" />
    <property name="DrainsLookSee" />
    <property name="DrainsFullCctv" />
    <property name="Soils" />
    <property name="Roots"/>
    <property name="Arb" />

    <loader query-ref="MI_MonthlyInstructionCount"/>
  </class>

  <sql-query name="MI_MonthlyInstructionCount">
    <return class="MonthlyInstructionCount">
      <return-property name="Month" column="Month" />
      <return-property name="MapRequests" column="MapRequests" />
      <return-property name="Instructions" column="Instructions" />
      <return-property name="DrainsLookSee" column="DrainsLookSee" />
      <return-property name="DrainsFullCctv" column="DrainsFullCctv" />
      <return-property name="Soils" column="Soils" />
      <return-property name="Roots" column="Roots" />
      <return-property name="Arb" column="Arb" />
    </return>
    <![CDATA[ 
    exec MI_MonthlyInstructionCount :StartDate, :NumberOfMonths
    ]]>
  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Cheers!