# NHibernate use Stored Procedure OR mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a mapping in NHibernate that works like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="BizEntities"
    namespace="BizEntities"
    default-lazy="false">
  <class name="SubscriberQueueItem" table="SubscriberQueueItem">
    <id name="SubscriberQueueItemId" column="Id" type="int" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="DateCreated" column="DateCreated"  type="DateTime" />
    <property name="CMIId" column="CMIId" type="int" />
    <property name="DateProcessed" column="DateProcessed"  type="DateTime" />
    <property name="EventStatus" column="EventStatusId" type="QueueStatusTypeValues, BizEntities" />
    <many-to-one  name="Subscription"  class="Subscription" column="SubscriptionId" />
    <property name="ErrorDescription" column="ErrorDescription" type="string" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and it's retrieved with simple queries against the table.

Is it possible to also map this class to a stored procedure?  I've got a procedure written that spits back a specific subsection of data that's difficult to write into an NHibernate query, but easy to write as a stored procedure.

Can I simply add a stored procedure mapping as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512272/correct-nhibernate-mapping-for-stored-procedure), and retrieve the object with direct mapping or stored proc based on my NHibernate query type, or does adding a stored procedure mapping to my hbm mean I can only retrieve based on that stored procedure?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to achieve but I think these two things are mutually exclusive. You might have a look on ayende posts : http://ayende.com/blog/1728/should-you-use-nhibernate-with-stored-procedure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stored procedures work just fine in NHibernate, I'm using them no problem :)

You'll need to add a "named query" into your hibernate mapping, like so:

```
<sql-query name="spMyProcedure">
    <!-- return type must be an NHibernate mapped entity -->
    <return alias="SubscriberQueueItem" type="BizEntities.SubscriberQueueItem, BizEntities" />

    exec spMyProcedure @Param1=:Param1, @Param2=:Param2
</sql-query>
```

If the return type of your stored procedure does not match an already mapped entity, you'll need to create a new one.

To invoke the sp, you'll need to add the following code:

```
var query = session.GetNamedQuery("spMyProcedure");

query.SetParameter("Param1", "hello");
query.SetParameter("Param2", "byebye");

SubscriberQueueItem result = query.UniqueResult<SubscriberQueueItem>();
```

Comment: So adding a named query for selects like that doesn't prevent you from doing normal NHibernate mappings (without using a stored procedure)?  Excellent!

Comment: Nope, you can still do direct table access where appropriate :)

Comment: NHibernate-mapping XSD does not define a 'type'attribute for the <return> element. http://hibernatingrhinos.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Caching/SharedLibs/nhibernate-mapping.xsd

Comment: @AdolfoPerez Looks like this may have changed in the 3+ years since I answered this question. If you have more up to date information please let us know :)